# Blank Screen on right scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the right side you can a see few pixels of space:

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove it? I think it's because of animations I have added with "aos" library. I have already had this error without animations, but I fixed it with this code:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is the link for the code so you can preview the page:

https://jsfiddle.net/5rq8grcL/

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/masaze.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  animation: fadeEffect 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#navbar-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

#navbar-list li {
  text-align: justify;
  display: inline;
}

#navbar-list li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#navbar-list li a:hover {
  color: #a0c2d5;
  transition: .5s;
}

.pocetna {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  float: left;
}

.linkovi {
  padding: 35px 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: 180px;
}

.linkovi:active {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

#main {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

#main h1 {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
}

#main h3 {
  font-size: 17pt;
}

hr {
  width: 615px;
  opacity: .2;
}

.button {
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3%;
}

.button a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #a0c2d5;
  transition: .5s;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

#video {
  background-color: rgba(20, 25, 25, 0.5);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 580px;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#section1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#section1 h3 {
  font-size: 25pt;
}

#section1 p {
  font-size: 18pt;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px gray;
}

#contact {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#section2 {
  font-size: 25pt;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/masaze.jpg");
}

#section2 h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.sectionc {
  display: table-cell;
}

.sectionc a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sectionc a:hover {
  transition: 0.5s;
  color: #a0c2d5;
}

#map {
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#section3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25pt;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-image: url("/assets/images/proba.jpg");
  height: 705px;
}

.kdn {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

#footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 80px;
}

#footer p {
  margin: -5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

#footer p a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#footer p a:hover {
  color: #a0c2d5;
  transition: .5s;
}

span {
  color: black;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

span:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Masaže Gligorijević</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/main.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="/assets/images/logo.png">
  <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Sans+Condensed:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul id="navbar-list">
        <li>
          <a class="pocetna" href="#"><img src="/assets/images/logo icon.ico" width="40" height="30" style="padding-right:10px;">Masaže Gligorijević</a>
        </li>
        <li class="linkovil"><a class="linkovi" href="#">Početna</a></li>
        <li class="linkovil"><a class="linkovi" href="#section1">O nama</a></li>
        <li><a class="linkovi m" href="#section2">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li><a class="linkovi" href="#section3">Kako do nas</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <header>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>Masaže Gligorijević</h1>
      <h3>Ulaganjem u svoje zdravlje, ulažete u kvalitet sopstvenog života.</h3>
      <hr>
      <button class="button"><i class="fas fa-play"></i> <a href="#section2">Rezervišite Odmah</a></button>
    </div>
  </header>

  <section>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="video">
            <source src="/assets/images/klip.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

    <div id="section1" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-easing="linear">
      <h3>O nama</h3>
      <p>
        Profesionalni maser i specijalno usavršeni fizioterapeut čija veština pokazuje odlične rezultate kod klijenata. <br><br> Naš salon je opremljen profesionalnom opremom. Masaže se obavljaju na stolovima za masažu.<br><br>Kompletnom uživanju doprinose
        prijatni zvuci muzike i mirisi aromatičnih ulja.<br> NAŠI klijenti odlaze uz pravilo: NAKON MASAŽE OPET IMAM OSMEH!
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="section2">
    <h3>Kontakt</h3>
    <div id="contact">
      <div id="sectionc" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-easing="linear">
        <h4>Zakažite vaš termin već sada!</h4>
        <p><i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i> Adresa: Ljubiše Uroševića 6/21, Jagodina</p>
        <p><i class="fas fa-mobile"></i> Tel: 060 078 2880</p>
        <p><i class="fas fa-at"></i> Email: milosgliga92@gmail.com</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="sectionc" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-easing="linear">
        <h4>Pratite nas na društvenim mrežama!</h4>
        <p><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i> <a href="https://sr-rs.facebook.com/Masa%C5%BEe-Gligorijevi%C4%87-Profesionalne-masa%C5%BEe-kinesio-taping-i-maderoterapija-1716964535194608/" target="_blank">Facebook</a></p>
        <p><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i><a href="https://www.instagram.com/gliga_massage_035/" target="_blank">Instagram</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <div id="section3" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-easing="linear">
    <h3 class="kdn">Kako do nas</h3>
    <div id="map">

    </div>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>
        &copy; 2018 <span>&nbsp; Đorđe Gligorijević &nbsp;</span> All Rights Reserved
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAvHllMfDUDEVM_GtdkQ6_hyj4wMJ2vVxM&callback=initMap"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/michalsnik/aos/2.1.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "*As you can see, on the right side you can a see few pixels of space*". I cannot see that.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j0yrdj This black line on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `#footer p`, remove `margin: -5px;` or at least change it to `margin: -5px 0px;`. The negative left and right margins are what's causing the gap.

Comment: Yup, this. I was going to suggest an `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` tag but that wouldn't address the root cause. Any tips for quickly identifying nested/obscured layout issues like this?

Comment: These ones are tough to track down. The easiest method that I've found is to scroll the content to create the gap that you are seeing and then, in Chrome Developer Tools, click the arrow icon that allows you to manually selected an element and run your cursor from top to bottom directly over top of the gap and watch what gets caught. Sometimes it's really tricky but you'll see the overflowing container get highlighted.

Comment: Cheers, [worked like a charm](https://codepen.io/uncleoptimus/pen/OvoOro) could see that being useful in the future! I was thinking to add an `outline: 1px solid someColor` to *everything* but your method saves extraneous rules.

Comment: Ah, yeah that would work too. I never gave that a thought.

Answer (score 0):

100% work. Try this

```
<script>$('[data-aos]').parent().addClass('hideOverflowOnMobile');</script>
<style>
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .hideOverflowOnMobile {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
</style>
```